# Apache Spark query, process and save from hive java.lang.ArrayStoreException

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I have a table in hive which I am querying via spark and doing some processing and then based on some conditions I want to store some values in the newly created table in code.

Below is the code that I have tried and few others too. But every time I get exception

```
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.appName("Spark Preprocess").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

import spark._
import spark.implicits._
val dataFrame = sql("select field1, field2, field3 from some_table).as[SomeTable]
val tableName = "ResultsTable_" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date())
sql("create table " + tableName + " (x bigint, y bigint)")
dataFrame.mapPartitions(partitionIterator => {
    var rows = List[Result]()
    partitionIterator.foreach( rowIterator => {
        //some calculation based on rows and calculate x and y (happens only in some cases
        rows = rows :+ Result(x, y)
    }
    Iterator(rows)
}.foreach(result => result.toDF().write.mode(SaveMode.Append).insertInto(tableName))

case class Result(x: Long, quantity: Long)
```

Exception

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuilder$ofRef.$plus$eq(ArrayBuilder.scala:87)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuilder$ofRef.$plus$eq(ArrayBuilder.scala:56)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2532)
```

Other things that I have tried are

```
foreach(result => result.toDS().write.mode(SaveMode.Append).insertInto(tableName))

foreach(result => sqlContext.createDataset(result).write.mode(SaveMode.Append).insertInto(tableName))
```